# Jquery to pure JS

Tags: javascript

I have some script in jquery, but i have a problem that on page i dont use Jquery, this is just example what i need, it is much more complex.

```
$('img').each(function(){ 
      $(this).removeAttr('width');
      $(this).removeAttr('height');
      $(this).addClass('img-responsive');
    });
```

It is for moving attributes from images and adding class responsive, because user uses a lot TinyMce and by default it is putting witdh and height. I know maybe there is some plugin for TinyMce but i need some common solution

Comment: Its very simple, you can search. [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),  [removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: jQuery is open source. Extract what you need from there.

Comment: why can't you just add jquery to that page as well? there is no cost if you use the same copy/url you serve on the other pages since the browser will have cached it.

Comment: Can someone make a anwser, please

Comment: Don't use jQuery tag, if you don't want answer in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work but you may need to modify for all browsers:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function (e) {
  e.removeAttribute('width')
  e.removeAttribute('height')
  e.classList.add('img-responsive')
})
```

See documentation for compatibility:

- [Element.removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)
- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Then use jQuery ;-)

Comment: @sp00m As i say i can not use jquery

Comment: You need to determine the support you require, then use the approach that fits. So, state your requirement.

Comment: Using `forEach` directly on a NodeList (what `querySelectorAll` returns) [isn't supported in Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility) (not to mention IE if for some reason you still have to support it). To be compatible with Edge you need to convert it to an array before calling `forEach` like [Sebastián's answer does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43000486/778975) or iterate over it with a loop like [Sandwell's answer does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43000457/778975).

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].removeAttribute("width");
    images[i].removeAttribute("height");
    images[i].classList.add("img-responsive");
}
```